# Comparing element in a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I just started learning Python... I am writing a simple program that will take in integers and keep an unsorted and sorted list.  I'm having a problem with the sorted list part...
I'm getting an error when comparing the values of elements within the list.  Where I get the error is the following line: "if sortedList[sortcount] > sortedList[count]:". I get "TypeError: unorderable types: list() > int()".

Here is part of the code... I'm not sure what is wrong.

```
numberList = []
sortedList = []
count = 0
sum = 0

....(skip)....

sortcount = 0
sortedList += [ int(userInput) ]
while sortcount < count:
    if sortedList[sortcount] > sortedList[count]:
        sortedList[count] = sortedList[sortcount]
        sortedList[sortcount] = [ int(userInput) ]  
    sortcount+=1
```

Comment: It'd be helpful to see the code where `sortedList` is being built.  It seems that your list contains a list, which I would think is an error somewhere in your `(skip)` section.

Comment: An easier way to update the sorted list would be `sortedList.append(int(userInput)); sortedList.sort()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

where you do:

```
sortedList[sortcount] = [ int(userInput) ]
```

you should do:

```
sortedList[sortcount] = int(userInput)
```

otherwise you will add a list on that position and give the error you told.

BTW, on the first line before the while loop is better to write

```
sortedList.append(int(userInput))
```

Comment: @JoelCornett: no, JBernardo is completely correct.  The OP sets the sortcount-th element of sortedList to [int(userInput)], which is a list.  There's no "adding a list" here.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using:

```
sorted(numberList)
```

to generate your sorted list. Much, much simpler not having to reinvent the wheel.

*Example:*

```
>>>unSorted = [3, 4, 1, 5]
>>>unSorted
[3, 4, 1, 5]
>>>sortedList = sorted(unSorted)
>>>sortedList
[1, 3, 4, 5]
```